# Selenium driver can't find any element after logging into a website [Python]

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

First of all if a similar topic occurred earlier I'm sorry but I couldn't find any problem like mine.

I would like to create a simple script which enters an e-mail website, log into my account and finds the amount of unread messages.

This is the part with logging in

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

class sMailBot():
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    def login(self):
        self.driver.get('website.com')

        sleep(2)

        btn_login = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="username"]')
        btn_login.send_keys('my_username')

        btn_password = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="password"]')
        btn_password.send_keys('my_password')

        btn_logintoaccount = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="button"]')
        btn_logintoaccount.click()

        sleep(5)
```

It works really well. After logging into my mail account comments like *driver.title* or *driver.current_url* work.

Now I would like to **scrape** this part of html code:

```
<b>some_important_string_which_stores_the_amount_of_unread_mails</b>
```

I tried to do this using it's path

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="MS_act1"]/span)
```

However it does not work. Moreover I can't find any other elements from this side.

I would like to highlight that I waiting even more than 10 seconds for the page to load.

The error which occurred

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="MS_act1"]/span/b"}
  (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.87)
```

As you asked I add some surrounding HTML code

```
<span style="float: right">
<b>some_important_string_which_stores_the_amount_of_unread_mails</b> 
</span>
```

Comment: It might be in an `<iframe>`. And it also seems you are looking for `<b>` tag, not `<span>`.

Comment: If you run the search from dev tools is it working ?

Comment: As Guy said, check if it's in an IFRAME. You said you are waiting 10s but in your code you are only waiting 5. 5s may not be enough. You should add a wait for 30s and see if that helps. Also, you please post more of the relevant HTML around the element you are looking for. Edit you question and add in the error message that is thrown when this fails. Thanks.

Comment: @Marco No it doesn't work.

Comment: @JeffC I provided the things you asked.

Answer (score 0):

Please, don't use `sleep`, it's not a good choice for selenium.

Instead, use selenium waits:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading")
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "myDynamicElement"))
    )
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Answer (score 0):

First of all I will avoid using sleep. You may try using [WebDriverWait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) instead. This will pause the browser until a given condition is satisfied.

e.g. as follows

```
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Login']")))
```

This will wait for 60 sec maximum for the element (button with text Login) to occur in the page.

Answer (score 0):

After logging into your mail account commands like `driver.title` and `driver.current_url` works but they are not part of the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes).

The relevant HTML would have helped us to construct a canonical answer. However to extract the desired text, you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR` and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[id^='MS_act'] span>b"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[starts-with(@id, 'MS_act')]//span/b"))).text)
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: I tried using your tips. Unfortunately it didn't work. I got **TimeoutException: Message: **

Comment: @Hendrra Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: @Hendrra Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: I tried again. The outcome was the same -- TimeoutException: Message: